# Hangfire Recurring job can't be scheduled

Tags: hangfire, hangfire-sql, hangfire-autofac, hangfire-console, hangfire.ninject

I am getting the below issue in my `Hangfire` recurring job after each 10 or 15 mins and every time I have to trigger my job manually and it starts working again for some time and then get the same issue.

What could be the cause of this issue?

> **System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details.**  --->
> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner
> exception for the details.  ---> System.TypeLoadException: Could not
> load type 'MyApplicaton.Api.Hangfire.UpdateFolder' from assembly
> 'MyApplicaton.Api, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'.    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(QCallAssembly assembly,
> String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,
> ObjectHandleOnStack type, ObjectHandleOnStack keepAlive,
> ObjectHandleOnStack assemblyLoadContext)    at
> System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetType(String name, Boolean
> throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)